# Can I use downcase! instead of downcase in a before_save hook to change a value?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, string, hook, before-save

I am new to Ruby. I am doing Michael Hartl's *Ruby on Rails Tutorial*, and the following code is used in the model for User:

```
before_save { self.email = email.downcase }
```

In this context, would it be acceptable to instead write:

```
before_save { self.email.downcase! }
```

or is this approached flawed for some reason? If it is, can you give me a quick explanation as to why?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! In my opinion this is a well-written question but I've made some minor edits to clean it up. You can check out [editing help](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) and [this discussion of salutations on Meta](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### TL; DR

> In this context, would it be acceptable to instead write
>
> ```
> before_save { self.email.downcase! }
> ```
>
> or is this approached flawed for some reason?

Don't do that unless the bang method is at the end of a method chain, or unless you know *for sure* that you don't care about the return value. Bad Things™ can happen otherwise.

Instead, you should use something that handles corner cases, like one of the following:

- `before_save { self.email.downcase! unless self.email.blank? }`
- `before_save { self.email = self.email.to_s.downcase }`

### Explanation

The problem with some bang methods like [String#downcase!](http://ruby-doc.org/core/String.html#method-i-downcase-21) is that they don't provide the return values you think they do. While `self.email.downcase!` will downcase the *email* attribute on self, the return value may be nil. For example:

```
"A".downcase!
#=> "a"

"".downcase!
#=> nil

"z".downcase!
#=> nil
```

Even worse, if *email* is nil an exception will be raised whether you use `downcase` or `downcase!`. For example:

```
nil.downcase
# NoMethodError: undefined method `downcase' for nil:NilClass
```

For the purposes of simply ensuring that the *email* attribute is lowercased, then you might get away with this in the narrow circumstance where [strong params](https://github.com/rails/strong_parameters) or other factors ensure that *email* is not nil, and where you aren't using the return value of your method or hook. More broadly speaking, though, a train wreck like:

```
before_save { self.email.downcase!.gsub(?@, ' AT ') }
```

might blow up in surprising and hard-to-debug ways at runtime.

To recap, your current examples *appear* functionally equivalent, but handle return values quite differently. Therefore, your mileage may vary.

Comment: Hey CodeGnome, thanks for the response. Thank you for being so thorough, I appreciate the explanation. I am new to rails and ruby also, so I am still learning about "Bad Things"... It is people like you who make the programming community so welcoming and... well... a community! Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Using `downcase!` to modify the attribute in place here is perfectly acceptable, as long as you can guarantee that `email` is set. In the case where `email` is `nil`, you will encounter a `NoMethodError` if you try to call `downcase!` on it. This also applies to your first example.

As an aside, there's really no need to specify `self` to access attributes on the model. The following is perfectly sufficient. (Adding a check for the presence of an e-mail.)

```
before_save { email.downcase! if email }
```

Comment: Hey Drenmi, I suspected it was acceptable... I will probably avoid using it however until I am more comfortable with the language. Thanks for the explanation about self as well... Makes perfect sense now. I appreciate you responding! Have a nice day, friend!

Answer (score 0):

The original method calls the attribute setter method `email=`, and therefore is the way to go:

```
self.email= email.downcase
```

ActiveRecord can then do additional things. For example it might track the changed attributes to optimise the database update.

When you change it with `downcase!`, you are first calling the getter, ActiveRecord returns the string, and then you change the string in place, and ActiveRecord is not directly aware of this. Maybe it works in this example, but it is safer not to get into this habit.

Comment: Hmm... good point. I probably won't get into this habit. I need to get more familiar with ActiveRecord and its tendencies. Thanks for your response, Meier. Seeya later!